# How do I try out my Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, developer-console

I'm just starting to learn SalesForce so forgive me if this question has an obvious answer. I've been creating a basic "display data in a table" component in the Developer Console. It catalogues movie posters just based on movie title and how many are in stock (count).

All I want to do is try out my code, but all I see in the "Poster" tab is the list of data I've made and not my component. How can I try out my code?

This is what I see:

[image: Poster list]

Here is my Apex controller:

```
public class PostroApexController {


    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Poster__c> getPosters(Id PosterID){

        return [Select ID__c, Count__c, Name From Poster__c Where ID = :PosterID];

    }

}
```

My XML component:

```
<aura:component controller="PostroApexController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome" access="global">
    Hello World
    <aura:attribute name="Poster" type="Poster__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Posters" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.performInit}"/>

    <lightning:datatable data="{! v.Poster }" columns="{! v.Columns }" keyField="ID" hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
</aura:component>
```

My JS controller:

```
({
    performInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        component.set("v.Columns", [
            {label:"Poster Title", fieldName:"Name", type:"text"},
            {label:"Count", fieldName:"Count__c"}

        ]);

        var action = component.get("c.getPosters");
        // set the args for getPosters(ID)
        action.setParams({
            PosterID: component.get("v.PosterID")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
           component.set("v.Posters", data.getReturnValue()); 
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

I'm looking for something that will let me see the data table I created in the component. Feel free to point out any other issues with my code too, I know it's awful and probably doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a lightning application to host your component and see if it works. You have to go to `File -> New -> Lightning Application` to create an app.

if your component name is posterComponent then markup for lightning application will be like

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:posterComponent />
</aura:application>
```

Once you create the Lightning Application, developer console even gives you an option to preview it.

[image]

I would recommend you to go through the basics here.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics